# AppEngine full-text-search queries inconsistent for devserver/unit test environment

Tags: google-app-engine, full-text-search

I've noticed an odd behavior of the "production" full-text-search functionality of AppEngine:

1) I build a text search index in App Engine with a field like "full_name" with values like "Kenny G" or "G Money" as well as one entry "G G":

```
final Index index = SearchServiceFactory.getSearchService().getIndex(IndexSpec.newBuilder().setName("MY_IDX").build());
index.put(Document.newBuilder().setId("doc1").addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("name").setText("G G"))
            .build());
index.put(Document.newBuilder().setId("doc2").addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("name").setText("G G G"))
            .build());
index.put(Document.newBuilder().setId("doc3").addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("name").setText("Kenny G"))
            .build());
index.put(Document.newBuilder().setId("doc4").addField(Field.newBuilder().setName("name").setText("G Money"))
            .build());
```

2) I then search the index using a query string of simply "G":

```
final QueryOptions options = QueryOptions.newBuilder().build();
final Query query = Query.newBuilder().setOptions(options).build("G");
for (final ScoredDocument doc : index.search(query).getResults()) {
    for (final Field field : doc.getFields()) {
        System.out.println(field.getType() + ": " + field.getName() + " - " + field.getText());
    }
}
```

In the devserver/unit test environment I get output of:

```
name (TEXT): G G
name (TEXT): G G G
name (TEXT): Kenny G
name (TEXT): G Money
```

Running the same thing in a JSP on "production" App Engine yields only:

```
name (TEXT): Kenny G
name (TEXT): G Money
```

Note that the document with field value "G G" (or "G G G" for that matter) is not returned.

Is there a documented limitation on minimum field length for indexing?  Clearly tokenizing accepts tokens of a single character or the "Kenny G" example would fail.  Very puzzling and LOOKS like a potential bug but perhaps I've missed something documented.

Comment: The search API is only "simulated" locally, and has some defined discrepancies here: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/search/devserver

Comment: But that does not directly answer your question. The min string length for tokenisation to occur does not look like a problem - in that the "G" in "Kenny G" has been indexed.

Comment: Try new documents with "G G G G ok" and "G"

Comment: not really sure why this works, partial matching should not be getting results.

Comment: Tom, thanks for your help!  I added "G G G G ok" and "G" to the set of documents and, in the devserver or unit test environments all documents are found.  In our "production" environment, "G" is found but "G G G G ok" is not.  Fun!  FWIW, we're using the Java environment rather than Python but nothing shown here seems to apply:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/search/devserver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The production servers implement a feature where a document text field containing consecutive single letters treats the group them as a unit.  If you search for [ggg] you should find the document that had the three G's.  The idea is that consecutive single letters are probably an acronym, and should be grouped.  Otherwise consecutive single letters don't generally appear in normal (English-language) text.

This is an example of an advanced feature that is not simulated in the devserver, unfortunately.

By the way, this behavior is sensitive to the language specified with the document.  For example, in French the behavior is different.

We plan to add documentation to clarify this feature.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer that thoroughly Alan.